# HASKELL: Get the height of a binary tree using a generalized foldr on binary trees

Tags: haskell

I need help with a university job. I've created a foldrBT function, which generalizes foldr on binary trees.

The exercise requires you to define the binary tree in this way

```
data BinTree a = R a (BinTree a) (BinTree a) | F a 
               deriving (Show)
```

Later I had to define the foldrBT function like this

```
foldrBT :: (t -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> BinTree t -> t1
foldrBT f v (F x) = f x v
foldrBT f v (R x lt rt) = f x (foldrBT f (foldrBT f v rt) lt)
```

In short, foldrBT acts on binary trees like foldr acts on lists. I try to show it to you with a graphic example

```
L = [a,b,c,d,e]   

foldr # z L  -> a#(b#(c#(d#(e#z)))

BT =    a    = R a (R b (F d) (F e)) (F c)
      /   \
      b    c
    /  \
   d    e  

foldrBT # z BT -> a#(b#(d#(e#(c#z))))
```

Now the exercise asks to use foldrBT to calculate the height of the binary tree but I can't figure out how to do it.

Basically, if I am on a root node (R) I calculate the height of the right and left subtree. I compare them and return the greatest height by increasing it by 1. If I am on a leaf (F) I return 0.

But for how foldrBT is defined, first I don't know how to check if I am on a root or on a leaf, and then the calculation of the height of the right subtree "concatenates" with that of the height of the left subtree giving me several problems in making a comparison between the two heights.

How could I solve. I have no more ideas :(

Comment: Do you need to know if you're looking at the root? Why or why not? Also, what happens at the "leaves" in a fold, in general? Think about what happens to the "leaf" when you fold over a list: what kind of thing or things would correspond to a "leaf" of a list? What happens to a "list leaf" when you fold over the list?

Comment: it's not clear why the constructors `F` and `R` in the definition you quote, and the last example, have become `S` and `P` in the `foldrBT` definition. I would recommend using intelligible names for your constructors, as with all values, not just single letter ones.

Comment: Writing down the type of `foldrBT` should be helpful.

Comment: As stated, this looks impossible to me: in your example you would get `a#(b#(d#(e#(c#z))))` for any tree having the same pre-order visit, AFAICS. But not all such trees have the same height, so there is no way to choose `#` and `z` suitably. For this exercise, I'd expect a different "fold" operation, such as the one known as a "catamorphism". Try checking whether your fold is indeed the intended one, or there's another you should use instead.

Comment: Great, now suppose you define `heightBT = foldrBT f z`, for some `f`. Now `heightBT` should return an `Int` so the type of `f` should be `a -> Int -> Int` and `z` should be `Int`. The height of the binary tree is determined by the highest of the two branches, so something like `max leftHeight rightHeight`. But `f` has only one `Int` argument. There is no way it can calculate a max of two anything because it doesn't have two anything.